# truncate all tables in laravel using eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, fluent

Is there a way I could truncate all the tables in a db using eloquent or fluent in laravel 4? I do not want to specify table names, I just want to truncate all the tables. In other words empty all the tables.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> NOTE: `doctrine/dbal` Package is Required for Performing this
>   Operations

So Make Sure that is Installed  `composer require doctrine/dbal`

### 1. Get all the table names

```
$tableNames = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableNames();
```

### 2. Loop through the array of table names and truncate with Schema Builder

```
foreach ($tableNames as $name) {
    //if you don't want to truncate migrations
    if ($name == 'migrations') {
        continue;
    }
    DB::table($name)->truncate();
}
```

> Help: If you have Got Some Error Such as

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint**

You Can disable foriegn Key Checks

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

and make sure to **ReEnable** it

```
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Comment: Note that Doctrine is going away as a dependency in Laravel 4.1, so this process will likely change when the new version is released.

Comment: good point @fideloper! but at least right now in the latest laravel/framework repo, the method is still there :)  Hopefully Taylor will add this listTableNames functionality when he does leave Doctrine behind.

Comment: is there a way to do this in Laravel 5?

Comment: yes, you just need to install "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5.0" manually.

Comment: If one doesn't want to delete the migrations table they can just do `php artisan migrate:reset`

Comment: Hi I have replied an answer based on yours. It supports laravel 5, disables foreign key problem, and do not need extra packages :)

Answer (score 16):

Here is my answer based on @Hao Luo. Moreover, it has these pros:

1. You **do not need to install any extra package** (no need for doctrine)
2. It supports Laravel 5 (or newer) very well
3. It disables foreign key constraint (If you truncate without caring about the orders and enables foreign key constraint, you will likely get an error)

Here is the code:

```
DB::statement("SET foreign_key_checks=0");
$databaseName = DB::getDatabaseName();
$tables = DB::select("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '$databaseName'");
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $name = $table->TABLE_NAME;
    //if you don't want to truncate migrations
    if ($name == 'migrations') {
        continue;
    }
    DB::table($name)->truncate();
}
DB::statement("SET foreign_key_checks=1");
```

Hope you like it! :)

Comment: Great, it works for laravel 5.7 on MySQL, no extra packages needed. Thank you.

Comment: **@fzyzcjy**, it is in my production now, I made a unit-test to test all my seeders using this piece. It is Amazing!!!

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev That's great!

Comment: How to truncate if the DB contain views also?

Answer (score 4):

In laravel 5, migrate:fresh will drop all the tables in the database (even if tables aren't related to migrate)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
// it do truncate all tables in database
   foreach($tables as $table){
      if ($table == 'migrations') {
          continue;
      }
      DB::table($table->Tables_in_portal_test)->truncate();
}
```

Remember you import

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

PD: Tables_in_YOUR_DATABASE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

This is how i truncate all tables inside a database (including table exceptions), it works for me.

```
    // set tables don't want to trucate here
    $excepts = ['migrations'];
    $tables = DB::connection()
    ->getPdo()
    ->query("SHOW FULL TABLES")
    ->fetchAll();
    $tableNames = [];

    $keys = array_keys($tables[0]);
    $keyName = $keys[0];
    $keyType = $keys[1];

    foreach ($tableNames as $name) {
        //if you don't want to truncate migrations
        if (in_array($name[$keyName], $excepts))
            continue;

        // truncate tables only
        if('BASE TABLE' !== $name[$keyType])
            continue;

        \DB::table($name)->truncate();
    }
```

Comment: Won't work on SQLite. Hao Luo answer works given you have DBAL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answers, I filter table names directly into the SQL query. I'm agree it's a small optimization but that avoids unnecessary loop.

```
protected function truncateDatabase($excepts = []): void
{
    $excepts = array_merge(['migrations'], $excepts);
    \DB::statement('SET foreign_key_checks=0');
    $table_names = \DB::query()->select('TABLE_NAME')->from('information_schema.tables')
        ->where('TABLE_SCHEMA', \DB::getDatabaseName())
        ->whereNotIn('TABLE_NAME', $excepts)
        ->get()
        ->pluck('TABLE_NAME')
        ->toArray();
    foreach ($table_names as $table_name) {
        \DB::table($table_name)->truncate();
    }
    \DB::statement('SET foreign_key_checks=1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your base test case class

```php
    protected static function truncateTableAll(array $skip = [])
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        
        foreach (Schema::getConnection()
                     ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
                     ->listTableNames() as $name) {
            
            if ($name == 'migrations' || in_array($name, $skip)) {
                continue;
            }
            DB::table($name)->truncate();
        }
        
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Laravel 8

i improved [Hao Luo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18910102/14629458)'s answer

Add this code to your `app/routes/console.php` file :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

.
.
.


Artisan::command('truncate', function () {

$this->comment('Truncating all tables');
 try{
     Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
     $databaseName = DB::getDatabaseName();
     $tables = DB::select("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '$databaseName'");
     foreach ($tables as $table) {
         $name = $table->TABLE_NAME;

         if ($name == 'migrations') {
             continue;
         }
         DB::table($name)->truncate();
     }
     Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
     $this->comment('Truncate finished.');
     $this->comment('Don\'t forget to run db:seed');
 }catch(Exception $e){
     $this->comment('Error !');
     $this->comment($e->getMessage());
     Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();#dont forget this if it fails
 }
})->purpose('Truncate all tables in database');
```

Now you can simply open terminal and run :

```
> php artisan truncate
```

Comment: Did not work for me. The error is "Method Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ClosureCommand::purpose does not exist."

Comment: @user1097111 remove `->purpose('Truncate all tables in database')`