# How to create mock model in laravel testing

Tags: laravel, testing, mocking

I need to test a function in `UserController` :

```
public function CreateUser(Request $request): Response
{    
    $user = User::firstOrCreate(['device_id' => $request->device_id]);
    return Response(['status'=> 'user created successfully'],200);
}
```

and I create a test function same as following:

```
public function testCreateUser()
{
    $mockUser = Mockery::mock(new App\User());
    $this->app->instance(App\User::class, $mockUser);
    $this->post(route('user_create'), ['device_id' => 'REC00ER']);
    ...
}
```

but this function create a real row in database. how to i can mock database for this request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create a new row in DB you can use `DatabaseTransactions`.

Just add it to your test:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;
...
```

More you can read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#working-with-databases) inside transactions.

Also, one [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554771/reset-the-records-in-the-database-in-laravel-during-testing-but-not-the-databas/57554840#57554840).

Good luck!

Comment: thanks its work for me, so can i delete `$mockUser = Mockery::mock(new App\User());` ?

Comment: @SinSin If you need you can use `$mockUser = User::create()` to create new user, and it will exist for testing purposes and the database will not be updated. If the answer is helpful please upvote it and mark. Thanks! :)

Comment: Is this method safe because I have important data in my database?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help